# Facebook error: "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (user_friends) on node type (User)"

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, permissions, facebook-login

I'm using MVC4 and try to integrate facebook-login. I've check the [facebook scope list](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_friends) and it appears I use it correctly. Except the error when I try to get `user_friends`

Here is the url I try to get:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=user_friends,email&access_token=<mytoken>
```

I get this error:

```
"{\"error\":{\"message\":\"(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (user_friends) on node type (User)\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"code\":100,\"fbtrace_id\":\"Ahhh3PoddnL\"}}"
```

If you must know, my app is now Public, can get email and basic info (the permissions was asked and I approved)

When I use as below everything is fine:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email&access_token=<mytoken>
```

Comment: For me the mistake was really silly, I was sending `get` request, instead of `post` lol

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`user_friends` is the name of the *permission* you need to request from the user, before you can access their friends.

It is *not* the name of the *endpoint* that you request the data from – that is `/me/friends`, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends

Comment: Thank you. I certainly did not realized before! Thank you so much.

Comment: It is possible to get friends list in iOS10?

Comment: @all I have got the same type of error `(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (likes) on node type (Post)` for getting the likes. I have added `user_likes` permission for the likes.