# Getting the crash Tried accessing nonexisting field (context) on node type (User) in android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

Suddenly I am getting the crash on this code which was working production code. What can be the cause of it

**I am using the Facebook graph api**

```
com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)
```

---

**Code I am getting the crash**

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("fields", "context.fields(mutual_friends)");
            new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/" + userProfileInfoModel.getFacebookId(), params, HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            facebookFriendsTagId.setText("");
                            fbFriendsApiCallForOtherFriends(response);
                        }
                    }
            ).executeAsync();
```

**Error:**

```
{Response:  
responseCode: 400, 
graphObject: null, 
error: {
HttpStatus: 400, 
errorCode: 100, 
subErrorCode: -1, 
errorType: OAuthException, 
errorMessage: (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (context) on node type (User)}}
```

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39266102/facebbok-error-100-tried-accessing-nonexisting-field-user-friends-on-node)?

Comment: `mutual friends` api was deprecated (and removed) as of 2018.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 04/23/2018

> **Mutual Friends**
>   The Mutual Friends API is no longer available.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#4-23-2018_6